# uninitialized constant GroupsController::Opentok

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video-streaming, opentok, tokbox

I am trying to build an app using **opentok**.I am following a [tutorial](https://railsfornovice.wordpress.com/2013/01/01/video-chatting-in-ruby-on-rails/).in tutorial he used a method and called through before_filer.

```
private
def config_opentok
if @opentok.nil?
 @opentok = OpenTok::OpenTokSDK.new YOUR_API_KEY, YOUR_SECRET_TOKEN
end
end
```

when i run the same code it shows..

```
uninitialized constant GroupsController::Opentok
```

how to initialize opentok instance variable.i changed YOUR_API_KEY and YOUR_SECRET_TOKEN to my own key and token.and i entered api_key without quotes and secret_token with quotes.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have the following line in your controller

```
require "opentok"
```

And use `OpenTok::OpenTok` instead of `OpenTok::OpenTokSDK`

[***Source***](https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-Ruby-SDK)

Comment: but it saying cannot load such file -- opentok, i even added opentok gem.

Comment: @ vjnan369 Did you installed the gem? Follow the link which i"ve given.

Comment: @vjnan369 Did you run `bundle install` ?

Comment: @vjnan369 Can you see the gem? Try running `gem list` and check if the gem is present or not.

Comment: are you there? opentok is in the gem list

Comment: @vjnan369 You have three versions of it. Keep the latest and remove the rest and check.

Comment: removed all older version kept 2.3.2,but still getting same error.even restart the server after bundle install

Comment: got it..i used OpenTok::OpenTok instead of OpenTok::OpenTokSDK which is given in link.thanks.@Pavan